# Angular 5 viewchildren not available in AfterViewInit hook

Tags: angular, angular5

In a component with a ViewChildren property, I want to create some SVG elements based on the data that each ViewChild contains.

If I place the logic in an AfterViewInit hook, the ViewChildren are not yet defined. I have tried a couple of approaches trying to use this hook with no luck.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // ViewChildren.first is undefined
    setTimeout(() => setupSVG(this.viewChildren), 0);

    // ViewChildren.first is undefined
    setupSVG(this.viewChildren);
}
```

However, if I place the logic in an AfterViewChecked hook it'll work but will be called many times once the view child contains its list of components.

```js
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (! this.viewChildren.first) {
        return;
    }

    setupSVG(this.viewChildren);
}
```

I have settled on a less than optimal solution using a static flag.

```js
class MyComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
    private static VIEW_LOADED = false;
    @ViewChildren('things') viewChildren: QueryList<AnotherComponent>;

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        if (! this.viewChildren.first) {
            return;
        }

        if (! MyComponent.VIEW_LOADED) {
            MyComponent.VIEW_LOADED = true;
            setupSVG(this.viewChildren)
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure there is a better way to handle this, any ideas or things I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but you should try to use the afterViewInit() of your children component here ?
The documentation said that your ViewChildren are set after the afterViewInit() of your component : https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

You should try something with an @Output from your children component.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you get results with that.